# For all sets $A, B$ and $C$: if $B\subseteq C$ then $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is this statement true:

> if $B\subseteq C$ then $A\setminus C\subseteq A\setminus B$?

If so, or if not, how would you prove it?

Sorry, I don't have my solution anymore, but I'll try and remember what I wrote. I assumed for all sets a,b,c, b is a subset of c. I will prove that A and not C is a subset of A and not B by contradiction, so let's assume that A and not C is not a subset of A and not B . From B being a subset of C, let x be an element of B and x be an element of C. Using our assumption, let x be an element of A and not C and since its not a subset of A and not B,then x is not an element of A and not B meaning that x is an element of B and from B being a subset of C we know that that means x is an element of C. However this contradicts our initial assumption that x is an element of A and not C. Thus we prove the statement by contradiction.

Comment: What have you tried? To show that a set is contained in another, you take an arbitrary element of the first set and show that it belongs to the second set.

Comment: I have tried proving by Contradiction but honestly I don’t know if it’s right I arrived at a contradiction but Now im wondering if it’s false

Comment: Can you write your solution then? Better not in the comments, you can just edit the question. Then we'll be able to see if you did it right.

Comment: Well we can not see if you have made any mistakes if we cannot see what you have done.

Comment: Proof by contradiction is the route to take.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Okay I put up my solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$.
Now $B\subseteq C$. That means that $x\notin B$, because if $x\in B$, then $B\nsubseteq C$.

But then $x\in A\setminus B$.